# Angular 2: How to render a multiple event in fullcalndar

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar in angular 2, Events for fullcalendar coming from other source, problem is how should i render the events which contain only multiple event on the day,need to hide or not clickable which show only single event.

Please help me

Comment: "events which contain only multiple event on the day". I don't understand this phrase. Do you mean you have events which contain other events within them?? Perhaps you can give an example of your data and your code. How have you tried to solve this so far?

Comment: mean i have to show the date, where date is having multiple events, and hide the other date which is having single event.

Comment: Which view type are you using for this? Month? Agenda? List? IMO any calendar with days completely missing from it is going to look confusing to users, who generally expect calendars to show all the days. If they don't look hard enough they might assume that the calendar shows Mon-Tue-Wed when in fact it really shows Mon-Thu-Sat because you hid the other days. What's the requirement for doing this? Are you sure it provides a good user experience? Maybe you should just _highlight_ the days with multiple events rather than making the others disappear entirely? Also what about days with 0 events?

Comment: Yes.I want to highlight the days with multiple events, and i did disappearing days with 0 events and also past days events.

Comment: basic approach: Create an empty array called "dates". Loop through all the events currently on the calendar (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/clientEvents/ gets you this data). Within the loop, for each event, look at its start and end dates. Get a list of all the days covered by the event. Loop the days. If you haven't seen the day before (i.e. it's not in your "dates" array), then add it to the array as an object e.g. { date: "2017-01-01": 1 } where "1" means there is one event on that day.

Comment: Keep looping through the events. Now, next time you see a day which you've found before, don't add a new array item, instea update the existing entry for that day and increase that day's count (e.g. from "1" to "2" etc.). Once your event loop finishes, then loop through your "dates" array. When you arrive at a date which has a count which is greater than 1, you know you need to highlight it on the calendar, and so you run the command to do that. That's the general idea. There may be a more efficient way to represent that in code, but that's the algorithm, off the top of my head.

Comment: yes.. I will try that algorithm.thanks a lot.